# IBM MobileFirst project migration 6.2.0.1 to 7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

While migrating 6.2.0.1 project to 7.0 following error is shown and project remains closed:

```
Starting to migrate the <project_name> project from version 6.2.0.01.20141027-1531 to version 7.0.0.00.20150312-0731

Unexpected error during upgrade: java.lang.Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: <path>/iphone/native/ExternalLibrary/iBeacon/NetworkServices.embeddedframework/NetworkServices.framework/Headers 
(No such file or directory) at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.performUpgrade(WLUpgradeEngine.java:326) at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.upgradeProject(WLUpgradeEngine.java:188) 
at com.worklight.studio.plugin.upgrader.WLUpgraderWorkspaceJob.runInWorkspace(Unknown Source) at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38) 
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54) Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: <path>/iphone/native/ExternalLibrary/iBeacon/NetworkServices.embeddedframework/NetworkServices.framework/Headers 
(No such file or directory) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146) 
at com.worklight.upgrader.internal.Zipper.addFileContentToZip(Zipper.java:145) at com.worklight.upgrader.internal.Zipper.addFolderToZip(Zipper.java:205) 
at com.worklight.upgrader.internal.Zipper.addFolderToZip(Zipper.java:202) at com.worklight.upgrader.internal.Zipper.addFolderToZip(Zipper.java:202) 
at com.worklight.upgrader.internal.Zipper.addFolderToZip(Zipper.java:202) at com.worklight.upgrader.internal.Zipper.addFolderToZip(Zipper.java:202) 
at com.worklight.upgrader.internal.Zipper.addFolderToZip(Zipper.java:202) at com.worklight.upgrader.internal.Zipper.addFolderToZip(Zipper.java:202) 
at com.worklight.upgrader.internal.Zipper.addFolderToZip(Zipper.java:202) at com.worklight.upgrader.internal.Zipper.addFolder(Zipper.java:106) 
at com.worklight.upgrader.internal.Zipper.addFolder(Zipper.java:91) at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.backupCurrentProject(WLUpgradeEngine.java:645) 
at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.performUpgrade(WLUpgradeEngine.java:294) ... 4 more 
[2015-03-31 10:31:58]             java.lang.Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: <path>/iphone/native/ExternalLibrary/iBeacon/NetworkServices.embeddedframework/NetworkServices.framework/Headers (No such file or directory)
```

Anyone has idea on possible cause and solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like an external folder and not part of the project.
Can you project step-by-step for reproducing and debugging the error?

A solution would probably be to put the ExternalLibrary/iBeacon folder outside of the project, import the project into MFP 7.0 Studio and then place the mentioned folder back into it and see if it works.

I suspect that unfamiliar folder confuses the upgrader.

Comment: Thank you Idan. Removing the folder fixed it (along with few other from external libs).
Project is migrated and I've moved the folder back. Now just need to do some testing to confirm everything works as it should but don't see why it would have any issues.

Thanks